# Equivalence Classes in software testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, equivalence-classes

I am new to Software testing and I am studying the basic techniques. I read the following problem:

**Identify the Equivalence Classes for the following specification: The program accepts five to nine inputs which are 3 digit integers greater than 100.**

I think that it doesn't matter how much inputs this program has, and the equivalence class is {99,100,101}. Am I right or not?

*After the comments, I think the classes are:*

```
1.(-00,99)
2.[100]
3.(101,999)
4.(1000,+00)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs:

- 0-4 inputs
- 5-9 inputs
- More than 9 inputs

Values:

- 0-100
- 101-999
- Greater than 999

The program accepts when there are between 5 and 9 inputs and each input value is a 3-digit number between 101 and 999.

Comment: I think that depending on the context, for example if the input is through command line arguments, there would exist other invalid classes such as "non integer numbers" and "alphanumeric inputs"

Answer (score 1):

equivalence classes  for your problem are:

1. set of numbers that are not three digit and greater than hundred...
2. set of numbers that are less than one hundred
3. set of numbers that are greater than one hundred and less than 999
4. set consisting of the number 100

Comment: the first class that you mentioned isn't the same with the second?@

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use PICT for generating effective combinations to test.
Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819137.aspx
The tool can be downloaded from http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/5/5/f55484df-8494-48fa-8dbd-8c6f76cc014b/pict33.msi

You can look for similar tools at http://pairwise.org/tools.asp

Comment: Interesting tool, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

```
1 0<x<100 , value of x should contain 0-4
2 101<x<999 , value of x should contain 5-9
3 X>999 , value of x should be 0-9
```

Answer (score -1):

Following should be the classes:
Inputs: 
`[0 - 4]` invalid class
`[5 - 9]` valid class
`[More than 9]` invalid class

Values:
`[Less than 99]` invalid class
`[100 to 999]` valid class
`[Greater than 1000]` invalid class

Again a Decision table should be used to find out the valid combination of Inputs and Values.